# Snapshot Movies

Tags: python, screenshot, snapshot, movie

I'm currently learning Python and have taken up several small projects to help learn the language.  Are there currently any libraries (possibly PythonMagick) out there that are capable of extracting snapshots from .wmv, .avi, .mpg, or other movie formats with only command-line options (no GUI)?  And if so, can anyone provide links to examples of code?

Answer (score 1):

A quick search in google revealed [pymedia](http://pymedia.org/tut/). It supports avi, dvd, wma, ...

Here is an [example](http://pymedia.org/tut/src/dump_video.py.html) on how to get snapshots from videos

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, if the CLI situation is not mandatory [Pyglet](http://www.pyglet.org) is exceptionally easy to use to load movies, images, etc. and is very well documented.